# How to save module configuration in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint, nano

I'm following a tutorial to boot Linux from usb3.0.

I stumbled across this tutorial:
http://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-on-a-usb-3-0-stick-and-boot-that-stick/

In the last section (configuration), it says to open up terminal and go /etc/.../module

I do this and add the following lines as the tutorial says to:

- xhci_hcd
- usbhid
- hid
- usb_storage

Now it says to save the file, but I don't know how?

Here is a picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fqps.png

Answer (score 0):

In nano use "WriteOut" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) to save the file.

Comment: Then I get this: http://i.imgur.com/DBLdrra.png

Comment: And how did you respond to that?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how. Sorry for all the questions. I'm new to this. Got to start somewhere.

Comment: Press Enter to accept the current filename, or use the other keys on the keyboard to edit it first.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell [Here](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/reu/nano.html) you can find quick guide on basic nano commands.